# How to find specific method removed in git commit histories

Tags: git

I used to have a older git project, in this project there is a specific method has been removed in the latest project. But I want to find out which commit has it removed, and find out the replacement method is. But use which git command to search in commit histories to find out that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the -S or -G flags:

```
   -S<string>
       Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the
       specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for
       the scripter’s use.

       It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a
       struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first
       came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the
       interesting block in the preimage back into -S, and keep going
       until you get the very first version of the block.

   -G<regex>
       Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines
       that match <regex>.
```

See also git-log(1) for more on the related "pickaxe" commands.